# Set not being called for array with getter/setter in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a number of bytes stored as an array. When any of these bytes values are changed, I want to use the setter to call another method. In the below example, this is a messagebox:

```
private byte[] numberArps = new byte[10] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };   // EEPROM 21
public byte[] NumberArps
{
    get
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Get called");
        return this.numberArps;
    }
    set
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Set called");
    }
}
```

This is called with the following code:

```
numberArps_textbox_1 = NumberArps[1].ToString();
NumberArps[1] = (byte)numberArps_textbox_1;
```

The messagebox "Get called" shows. Strangely, the code within the set {} braces is never reached even when debugging, the value is in fact stored in the array.

Is this error due to using array getter/setter incorrectly, or an error in implementation?

Comment: `NumberArps[1]` is not `NumberArps`. Doing `NumberArps = new byte[10]` will call the set.

Comment: You're not assigning the array, but an element. It's not gonna work like this. You could create a wrapper [Indexed Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288464(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: My class just contains a number array members. For example:
private byte[] bankEnabled = new byte[10]
private byte[] numberArps = new byte[10]
Would Indexed Properties still be the best method for this?

Comment: Your property is the whole array, not the element of the array. when you initialize that's when the setter is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are setting an individual value, not the property directly. Setter would only get called if you set it like this:

```
NumberArps = new byte[5];
```

If you want to control changes in the collection, get notified when item is added/modified, try using [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx).